# Setting the queue is calling the observer?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I am making a music player, and for some reason when I add the notification center observer and set the queue and play the song it gets called twice. I commented out the play method and it's only called once. I'm not sure how to fix this or whether this is the issue.

didLoad

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(change), name: .MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange, object: nil)
musicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
```

change function

```
@objc func change() {
   print(musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem?.title) //called twice
}
```

function to queue and play

```
musicPlayer.setQueue(with: queueArr)
musicPlayer.play()
```

Comment: Check how many times is called `didLoad()`. A guess is that it's called multiples times, potentially due to a dealloc/deinit not called.

Comment: Agree with @Larme. What is `didLoad` method?

Comment: @Larme nope its called just once.

Comment: Like I said its cause of setQueue and play, thats why its being called twice

Comment: can you post the class of your musicPlayer? @joethemow